# COUNT select and local variable storage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to find the id of the person with the least number of clients associated to them, inorder that the current new client is allocated to this staff member.

I've used the following to establish the id of this staff member as follows;

```
    SELECT TOP(1) JA.judgeID, COUNT(JA.judgeId) AS COUNT
    FROM recJudgeAssignment AS JA
    LEFT JOIN recEntrantStatus AS ES
    ON JA.bandId = ES.entrantId
    GROUP BY JA.judgeId, ES.roundId
    HAVING ES.roundId = @round
    ORDER BY COUNT
```

But I need to catch this as a local variable to use in the next statement;

```
    UPDATE recJudgeAssignment
    SET judgeId = @judge
    WHERE roundId = @round
    AND bandId = @entrantId
```

How do I catch the judgeId in the 1st select? Normally I would do something like;

```
    SELECT @judge =(SELECT TOP(1) JA.judgeID, COUNT(JA.judgeId) AS COUNT
    FROM recJudgeAssignment AS JA
    LEFT JOIN recEntrantStatus AS ES
    ON JA.bandId = ES.entrantId
    GROUP BY JA.judgeId, ES.roundId
    HAVING ES.roundId = @round
    ORDER BY COUNT)
```

This doesn't work of course because the select is returning the judgeId and the COUNT. I would prefer to not have to send the result of the 1st select back to the webpage and then do the subsequent update statement in a seperate web>db transaction.

So... Any help or even remedies anyone can offer, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have an MSSQL server handy to test, but couldn't you just put the aggregate function `COUNT(JA.judgeId)` in your `ORDER BY` clause (rather than including it in your `SELECT`)?

Comment: I'll try now, but it sounds like a good possibility.

Comment: @Crontab No. That doesn't work. it just returns -1 code and no result/records

Comment: A you sure I just tested a count in the order by?  Check that having - if it is not an aggregate the why in having? select top 1 sID from docMVtext group by sID order by COUNT(sID) asc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-- Query the DB for your variables
-- (I have also moved the HAVING clause to a WHERE clause.)
------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT TOP(1)
  @judgeID = JA.judgeID,
  @count   = COUNT(JA.judgeId)
FROM
  recJudgeAssignment AS JA
LEFT JOIN
  recEntrantStatus AS ES
    ON JA.bandId = ES.entrantId
WHERE
  ES.roundId = @round
GROUP BY
  JA.judgeId, ES.roundId
ORDER BY
  COUNT

-- Update the DB
------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE
  recJudgeAssignment
SET
  judgeId = @judgeID
WHERE
      roundId = @round
  AND bandId  = @entrantId

-- Return the variables to the client
------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT
  @judgeID     AS judgeID,
  @count       AS count
```

Comment: Unfortunately this complains of an invalid column name 'COUNT' Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @PhillHealey - Should be `ORDER BY COUNT(JA.judgeId)`

Comment: @Martin Smith - Thought so. Just wanted to be sure. Thanks for the confirmation. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT top(1) @judge = JA.judgeID, @count_j =COUNT(JA.judgeId)
    FROM recJudgeAssignment AS JA
    LEFT JOIN recEntrantStatus AS ES
    ON JA.bandId = ES.entrantId
    GROUP BY JA.judgeId, ES.roundId
    HAVING ES.roundId = @round
    ORDER BY COUNT
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. By mistake, while editing I removed the top(1).

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the first query
Please try this

```
SELECT TOP(1) JA.judgeID
FROM recJudgeAssignment AS JA
LEFT JOIN recEntrantStatus AS ES
 ON   JA.bandId = ES.entrantId 
 AND  ES.roundId = @round   
GROUP BY JA.judgeId, ES.roundId
ORDER BY COUNT(JA.judgeId)
```

Comment: It looks like that would work, but I'm going with the answer from @Dems above as it give me the possibility to output the result too. Thanks for the response thought. It's really appreciated. thanks.